# unit test for exporting XML method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, c#-4.0, nunit

I have a method `ExportXMLFiles(string path)` to export xml files at a certain path with some elements inside it like FirstName, LastName, MajorSubject. These values are getting picked from a database.

Now I need to write a Unit test method for it and I have not worked on much unit tests except simple and straight forward ones. My confusion is, do I need to connect to database and create a XML file or do I need to pass hard coded values while creating XML file so that I can validate the values in XML created?

Is there any other way for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely do not want to use an actual database in your unit test. It adds one level of complexity that you don't want to deal with in your unit tests. It also makes your unit tests less reliable and slower. See if you can break the database functionality into an interface that you can instantiate using a mocking framework. Try looking into something like [moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) or if that isn't enough check out [moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) from Microsoft .

Edit - Another post mentioned that if the functionality is to write to the disk then your unit test should validate that the file was written out to disk. Using Moles you can simulate file systems and test your file system calls and simulate write failures or whatever other cases you need which would give you a lot more flexibility and speed than actually physically writing to disk. Things like a disk write failing would be miserable to test without something like moles.

Answer (score 0):

A unit test should be small in scope and isolated from dependencies eg databases and file systems. So what you want to do is look at mocking out the database access and what would get written to a file so that you can run your test without needing particular values in the database. Unit tests should be fast to run, have repeatable results (ie run twice, get the same answer), isolated from other tests and able to be run in any order.

A unit test is looking at ONE item of functionality and not relying on the behaviour of anything else.

So look at using a pattern such as dependency injection so you can provide (ie inject) database and file system dependencies. Look at a mocking framework such as NMock or write your own lightweight fake objects that implement the same interface as the dependencies and then you can pass those into your functions being tested.

Answer (score 0):

What is the responsibility of this method ?
Is it to dump given data in the form of xml files at a certain path? If yes, then you'd have to check that the files are in fact created.

This is not a unit test but an integration test (because this is the class at the boundary between your app and the filesystem). You should abstract away the input data source (the DB) via an interface/role. You can also create a Role to CreateXmlFile(contents) but I think that's overkill.

```
// setup mock data source to supply canned data
// call myObject.ExportToXml(mockDataSource, tempPath)
// verify files are created in tempPath
```

Finally this class needs to implement a Role (DataExporter) so that the tests that use DataExporter are fast / don't have to deal with filesystems (or XML).